# ～かなんだか meaning in this sentence

Tags: grammar, slang

I'm dealing with some TV character's lines that speak in slang.

Speaking about a snob girl, she say this to another character near to her:

> 名門**かなんだか**知らねえが、あのうえから目線が本当にむかつくぜ。

To me, the general meaning seems to be "I don't care if she came from a noble family, (but) that her haughty behaviour really piss me off!", but I can't figure out what is that "かなんだか", before 知らねえ.

May you help me to understand? Thks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 「Word/Phrase + **（だ）かなん（だ）か** + 知{し}らない」

should be remembered as a set phrase meaning:

> "I don't care (if something/someone is) ~~ ***or whatever***"

My own TL:

> "I couldn't care less if she's from a distinguished family or whatever.  That arrogant attitude of hers just pisses me off."

Comment: Thk u! By chance, Can you tell to me something also about that "が" after 知らねえ? In other words, if I had to explain it to someone, how can I explain that が? It's maybe just a が for "but"? A が that have sense in japanese but not in English?

Comment: That が is a conjunction that is sometimes closer to "but" than to "and" and somtimes the other way around.  It is used VERY often and it is even used at the end of a sentence.  In the case of the sentence above, it is used as a "light" kind of "but", which is why I did not even translate it as "but".

Answer (score 0):

You pretty much have the meaning down. 何だか can mean "somehow" or "kinda/sorta" depending on the context. Here, I would translate that part as, "I don't really know about her being from a noble family, but..."

The 名門か part is short for 名門かどうか, implying, "whether or not (she's from a) noble family..."

Then you move on to 何だか知らねえが… which, again, I'd translate as, "I don't really know about that..."

See how 何だか is used in this example sentence. It might help everything click.

> なんだか知らないけど自然{しぜん}に覚えちゃったんだよね。I don't know how, but I just picked it up
>   naturally. [Link](http://jisho.org/sentences/51867afdd5dda7e98101b2bc)

Comment: Looks like you are talking about another kind of なんだか.

Comment: Umh, sorry, I forgot to write that she knows that the other girl come from a noble family.